# Downgrade mongodb from v3.2.10 to v2.4.9, keeping the same data files

Tags: mongodb

I have the /data/db files from a MongoDB v3.2.10 installation using WiredTiger. How can I run MongoDB v2.4.9, on ubuntu, in a way that it can use the same data files in /data/db?

FYI, I have copied /data/db to the new mongodb directory, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: which new db version you are installing? what was the old version?

Comment: my old version is 3.2.10 and new version is 2.4.9

Comment: you're downgrading from 3.2.10 to 2.4.9?

Comment: Even though it sound fantastically funny, IT IS YES.

Comment: take a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-downgrade/#downgrade-considerations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import a datapath, you can pass the dbpath flag to the mongodb daemon when initializing it. Example:

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db
```

If you want to restore a previous mongodb dumpfile, you can use the mongorestore option. Example:

```
mongorestore --db yourDB /data/db
```

This will restore your /data/db to a new database called **yourDB**

Hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: thanks for the quickly reply. while I type the command as you suggest mongorestore --db yourDB /data/db, it prompt 'don't know what to do with file *******.wt';  but there are tow collection storage and system.indexes in myDB nevertheless.  however, I can not find my data thanks.

Comment: @suoyong if you have files ending _.wt_, those are [WiredTiger storage engine data files](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/), not the BSON files from a [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/).

Answer (score 0):

No: the files are incompatible because they are from a different storage engine.

Your v.3.2 installation was running with the [WiredTiger storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/); that is why your data files have the *.wt* extension. This [storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/storage-engines/) was only [introduced in MongoDB v3.0](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/wiredtiger/); before that, the only storage engine available was [MMAPv1](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/mmapv1/).

So your MongoDB v2.4.9 can only run with MMAPv1 data files; when you give it WiredTiger data files, it does not know what to do with them and fails.

If you have to downgrade, then you will need to use mongodump as part of a conversion of the data from one storage engine to another:

1. run MongoDB v3.2.10 with the WiredTiger data files
2. run [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) to produce a BSON dump of the entire database.
3. install MongoDB v3.2.10
4. install MongoDB v2.4.9
5. run [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) to import the data from the BSON files into the MMAPv1 data storage engine.